# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - why am I still having this problem?

Tags: console, multidimensional-array, chess

I'm trying to print a chessboard to the console using a 2D array. For testing purposes, I'm trying to simply populate the board as 'x' chars. However, I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when I try to populate the array with the following:

```
public void setupBoard(){
        for (int i=0; i < height; i++){
            for (int j=0; j < width; j++){
                boardArray[i][j] = 'x';
            }
        }
    }
```

The error apparently occurs at `boardArray[i][j] = 'x';`

Everything seems to be in order, I dont see why this isnt working.

EDIT: I got the array to populate, but now I cannot format the printing correctly. The contents all print on one line, instead of as an 8x8 square of 'x' chars. Here's what I have now:

```
public void displayBoard(){
        for (int k=0; k < boardArray.length; k++)
               for (int l=0; l < boardArray[k].length; l++){
                   System.out.print(boardArray[k][l]);
               }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is Java, but it would be good to tag it as such...

Answer (score 3):

Well, presumably it's because you haven't created the board properly. Unfortunately you haven't shown us the array creation statement. It *should* be something like:

```
char[][] boardArray = new char[height][width];
```

EDIT: Okay, now for the printing part. Your current code is:

```
public void displayBoard(){
    for (int k=0; k < boardArray.length; k++)
           for (int l=0; l < boardArray[k].length; l++){
               System.out.print(boardArray[k][l]);
           }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
public void displayBoard() {
    for (int k = 0; k < boardArray.length; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < boardArray[k].length; l++) {
            System.out.print(boardArray[k][l]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

... so you're only calling `println` after the *outer* loop has finished. If you just move the call to `println` to after the *inner* loop, it'll be fine:

```
public void displayBoard() {
    for (int k = 0; k < boardArray.length; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < boardArray[k].length; l++) {
            System.out.print(boardArray[k][l]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Note that this sort of thing is clearer if you *always* include braces for loops, `if` statements etc.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: I got it to populate, but my problem is now printing. It prints all on one line.

Comment: Use `System.out.println(boardArray[k][l])` for new lines.

Comment: @zengr: That will put the whole thing in one long column, which I suspect isn't what's wanted either.

Comment: oh wow, thanks. I didnt even notice I was missing a bracket. :D